# jQuery check object if it exists

Tags: jquery, object

Have an object which I am trying to handle in jQuery if the details contain a text. Searched all around but nothing works, for instance this doesn't work:

```
if(typeof data.details[0].text !== "undefined") {JScode}
```

Format 1 (json):

```
data = {kod: 4007, text: "Test.", details: []}
```

Format 2 (json):

```
data = {kod: 9004, text: "Test.", details: [{code: 9999, text: "Error"}]}
```

Comment: The object name is `details`, right? Have you tried details.text? And details.details.text?

Comment: Is `details` a jQuery object? If so, it'd have to be `if(details.text())`

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/ Had you given the error message, it'd have been so much easier to solve.

Comment: Uhm, if details can be empty array or not I would do this check: `data.details.length !== 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check if `details[0]` before you can check `details[0].text` is undefined.

Here is some snippets:

```js
let obj = {kod: 4007, text: "Test.", details: []}

if (typeof obj.details[0] !== "undefined" && typeof obj.details[0].text !== "undefined") {
  console.log("Defined");
} else {
  console.log("Undefined");
}
```

```js
let obj = {kod: 9004, text: "Test.", details: [{code: 9999, text: "Error"}]}

if (typeof obj.details[0] !== "undefined" && typeof obj.details[0].text !== "undefined") {
  console.log("Defined");
} else {
  console.log("Undefined");
}
```

Comment: That can be shortened alot: `if(obj.details.length && obj.details[0].text)`

Answer (score -1):

Try using `.length`:

```
if (details[0].text.length > O) { it should exist }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.